# Copy content of a oracle table in a c# List

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am developping an asp.net application. For some reasons, I would like to copy specific columns of my table in a c# collection like a list.

I have a table called Users, with the following fields : name, surname, age.
I would like to have a List of these records (only name and surname fields).

So I created a class User.cs :

```
public class User {
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string surname{ get; set; }
}
```

And this is my what I what I've started in my home_page.aspx.cs, which is not working as the db object has no method query :

```
List<User> oracleList;
        using (var db = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            db.
            oracleList = db.Query<User>("SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM USERS");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

OracleConnection has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260 
Maybe it's not the best way, but it works:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        List<User> oracleList = new List<User>();
        string cmd = "SELECT name,surname FROM users";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            dAdapter.Fill(ds);
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                User user =new User();
                user.name=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"];
                user.surname=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["surname"];
                oracleList.add(user);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do something
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```